# Complete graph checking

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

How can I check for a complete graph (that is,each node is connected to each other nodes) in an efficient way? The given graph is undirected and non-weighted.

I have used BFS to check but it's not efficient way to check for all nodes,

```
1 <= number of nodes <= 10^4
```

Is there any other approach which help me to this task?

Comment: 10^8 edges seem to be quite a large amount, which will take about one second to compute.  If you're going to be checking for completeness multiple times, there might be a better algorithm to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `n` number of nodes ,There are `n*(n-1)/2` edges.
so you can easily check for the complete graph

Comment: Iff there are no self-loops.

Answer (score 2):

To be a complete graph:

1. The number of edges in the graph must be `N(N-1)/2`
2. Each vertice must be connected to exactly `N-1` other vertices.

Time Complexity to check second condition : `O(N^2)`

Use this approach for second condition check:

```
for i in 1 to N-1
 for j in i+1 to N
   if i is not connected to j 
   return FALSE
return TRUE
```

Comment: I am not sure that #2 is necessary. If you have `N` vertices and `N(N-1)/2` edges, it is enough in order to be a complete graph. Am I wrong?

Comment: @A.Sarid yes that is wrong. Say if only `two` vertices out of `N` vertices have all the `N*(N-1)/2` edges connecting two of them, that doesn't mean it is `connected`.

Comment: Well, this can't be because each vertex can have maximum of `N-1` outgoing edges.

Answer (score 1):

A **complete** (**undirected**) graph is known to have exactly `V(V-1)/2` edges where `V` is the number of vertices.

So, you can simply check that you have exactly `V(V-1)/2` edges.

```
count = 0
for-each edge in E
    count++
if (count == V(V-1)/2)
    return true
else
    return false
```

Why is this correct?
If each vertex is connected to all other vertices then each vertex has exactly `V-1` edges. This is `V(V-1)`. So why are we dividing by `2`? This is because in our counting each edge is connected to another vertex, so we counted each edge twice. Finally we get `V(V-1)/2` edges total.

Comment: number of vertices choose 2

Answer (score 1):

If no more additional information is given then we must check all nc2 edges. As is told in the accepted answer.
But we can improve if one more information is added.

If the graph does not have multiple edges between two nodes. That is, there is at most one edge between two nodes this algorithm can be useful.

Check if the number of connected components is 1. Else answer is no.
Now if the number of edges is N*(N-1)/2 then yes. Else no.

Answer (score -4):

for n

```
1<=n<=10^4
```

number of nodes ,There are

```
= n*(n-1)/2
```

edges. so you can easily check for the complete graph

Comment: Why would you simply copy the accepted answer without providing any new info? -1.